# Qt abstract buttom . How to draw the background in different z levels to avoid background overlaping with other buttons

Tags: c++, qt

I have design a Qt object derived from QAbstractButton. It has some transparent drawings that I use in the background and an opaque solid shape for the foreground.

The background is big, as a shadow, and two objects could be close and partially overlapped.

Foregrounds never overlap between then (by design) but background could overlap the other object (in both areas).

What I want to do is to draw foreground and background in different levels. I mean,  first tp draw the backgrounds and then the foregrounds, in that way I will never overlap the foreground area.

Is it possible?

I'm using Qt 5.12.

Update: Adding some sketches

[image: The current situation]

[image: Expected result]

B2 yellow background is drawed over B1 solid foregraund, and it is not desired.

Comment: I have read this two times and I do not understand at all what you are trying to achieve. Could you attach some picture of the desired effect?

Comment: It doesn't look like something you need to create class for. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qpushbutton https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-a-qpushbutton-using-the-box-model

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile I've added some horrible drawings. Hope it helps to understand.

Comment: @MarekR My background not is a gradient of flat color, or perhaps I don't get the point.

Comment: Ok so basically you need **two** overlapping buttons, but background of one button should be behind foreground of the other button. Now background form one button overshadows foreground of other. Isn't easier just do one common background and put buttons on top of it?

Comment: @MarekR your proposal is very similar to my workaround, the buttons are in a QGraphicsScene, so what I did is create another items, let the button background transparent and paint what I want to paint in the QGraphicsScene::drawBackground event. I prefer to do it directly but is a solution and it works. Thanks